# Data Cleaning in R

Tags: r, csv, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a `csv` file which I want to extract only the timestamp of the sentences which contain toward plus the fruit name in that sentence. How can I do this in R (or if there's a faster way to do so, what's that?)

```
rosbagTimestamp,data
1438293900729698553,robot is in motion toward [strawberry]
1438293900730571638,Found a plan for avocado in 1.36400008202 seconds
1438293900731434815,current probability is greater than EXECUTION_THRESHOLD
1438293900731554567,ready to execute am original plan of len = 33
1438293900731586463,len of sub plan 1 = 24
1438293900731633713,len of sub plan 2 = 9
1438293900732910799,put in an execution request; now updating the dict
1438293900732949576,current_prediciton_item = avocado
1438293900733070339,current_item_probability = 0.880086981207
1438293901677787230,current probability is greater than PLANNING_THRESHOLD
1438293901681590725,robot is in motion toward [avocado]
1438293902689233770,we have received verbal request [avocado]
1438293902689314002,we already have a plan for the verbal request
1438293902689377800,debug
1438293902690529516,put in the final motion request
1438293902691076051,Found a plan for avocado in 1.95595788956 seconds
1438293902691084147,current predicted item != motion target; calc a new plan
1438293902691110642,current probability is greater than EXECUTION_THRESHOLD
1438293902691885974,have existing requests
1438293904496769068,robot is in motion toward [avocado]
1438293907737142498,ready to pick up the item
```

Ideally I want the output to be something like this:

```
1438293900729698553, strawberry
1438293901681590725, avocado
1438293904496769068, avocado
```

So apparently I have to use `subset` in `grep` for `R` but I am not really sure how to!

Comment: Do you have a vector or other object that contains the names of the fruits you want your code to recognize?

Comment: @ulfelder I don't have a vector but yeah, I know that there is only 15 of them so they are limited. How would that help?

Comment: If you're going to ask the code to look for something in those strings, you need to tell it what to look for. Unless the name of the fruit always comes immediately after the word 'toward' or is the only thing that ever appears in brackets, in which case you should be able to dodge that problem. Is at least one of those conditions true?

Comment: yeah, the name of fruit always comes directly after the "towards" inside the bracket @ulfelder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stamps <- df$rosbagTimestamp[grep("toward \\[", df$data)]
fruits <- gsub(".*\\[(\\w+)\\].*", "\\1", df$data[grep("toward \\[", df$data)])
data.frame(stamps,fruits)
               stamps     fruits
1 1438293900729698560 strawberry
2 1438293901681590784    avocado
3 1438293904496769024    avocado
```

I used the pattern `"toward \\["` to locate fruits. If any changes occur in variability, it can be extended. The `stamps` variable is created by locating time stamps that have the pattern in the data column. The `fruits` variable isolates the fruit inside of the brackets.